# Error on installing Azure Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm following [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-4.4.1) tutorial to install Azure PowerShell. And, on step 2 of the tutorial I'm getting the following error when I run the following command specified in the tutorial:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Install-Module AzureRM -AllowClobber
```

> Install-Module : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'AllowClobber'.
>   At line:1 char:24
>   + Install-Module AzureRM -AllowClobber
>   +                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Install-Module], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Install-Module

Comment: What tutorial? Did you forget to send a link?

Comment: -AllowClobber is used during “import” not “install.” There’s two separate commands.

Comment: @Appleoddity I've added the link to the Microsoft tutorial. See if that can help you sharing your thoughts. Thank you for pointing out that I forgot to adding the link.

Comment: You can forego using the `-allowclobber` parameter. It's not important. But, you probably are not running the newest version of powershell: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can download this MSI package to install it.

Here is the [Azure PowerShell version 4.4.1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/download/v4.4.1-October2017/azure-powershell.4.4.1.msi), please download it and install it.

By the way, we can use this command to install it.

```
Install-Module -Name AzureRM
```

Comment: The MSI package you referenced helped (thank you)..

Comment: I found the latest MSI here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases though I had to unintall what I had before it would install